# Graph-tool for python not imported on Pycharm

Tags: python, graph-tool

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graph_tool'
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyLXK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmvXq.png)

I've been trying to fix this issue for a couple of days now with no success. Pycharm and Python 3.11 was installed via home-brew. From my understanding the problem is that graph-tool is not linked to my python. I've tried linking to no avail.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PyCharm. PyCharm just provides you access to specific Python environments, and it would appear that the environment set for your project in PyCharm doesn't have that package installed. Check your Project Settings from the File menu, and see what interpreter is selected - if you have a virtual environment with the package installed, switch to that, or create a new one and install it into that.

Comment: How, exactly, did you install graph_tool?